# How to preserve ASCII control characters when loading into BigQuery

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, ascii

I'm trying to import data into a BigQuery table from a CSV file using Bigquery python API. Since, it contains some ASCII control characters, loading job is getting failed with below error.

`CSV file contains the ASCII 0 (NULL) character, you can't load the data into BigQuery.`

[image: bigquery documentation]

It is observed that we can allow ascii control characters by setting ***--preserve_ascii_control_characters=true*** from bq command line ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)). But the same functionality cannot be found via python API. Is there any work around to avoid this issue?

sample code:

```
import six

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
)

body = six.BytesIO(b"Washington,WA")
client.load_table_from_file(body, table_id, job_config=job_config).result()
previous_rows = client.get_table(table_id).num_rows
assert previous_rows > 0

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
)

uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Comment: It seems that this feature is not available in Python or other client libraries. A feature request with regards to this issue is created. See https://issuetracker.google.com/240743062.

Comment: Thanks @RiccoD , is there any work around that can be suggested?

Comment: As per [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/240743062), workarounds are 1.) use REST API and set JobLoadConfiguration preserveAsciiControlCharacters to true, 2.)  bq command line using flag --preserve_ascii_control_characters=true. So you either send requests to the REST API via python or call the bq command in your python script.

Answer (score 1):

It is yet to be added to libraries from Google's end but till then we can use this

```
job_config._properties["load"]["preserve_ascii_control_characters"] = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ricco D in the  comments, `preserve_Ascii_ControlCharacters` is yet to be implemented for BQ client Libraries. You can follow this [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/240743062) to get updates on when the feature is rolled out.

Meanwhile you can follow the following workarounds:

- [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationload) and set JobLoadConfiguration `preserveAsciiControlCharacters` to `true`
- bq [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bq_1%60) line using flag `--preserve_ascii_control_characters=true`